# Webkit Speech Recognition API: Single Syllables

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm trying to use Webkit Speech Recognition API to recognize single syllables, rather than full words or sentences.
As this API requires "grammar" definition, I wonder if there is a way to implement single syllable recognition. Something like "ah" or "bi".

Thanks

Comment: There is a way that you can set `grammars` in `SpeechRecognition` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/grammars but you need syllables... And syllables are a lot... Perhaps you could create you own grammar using this https://github.com/tur-nr/node-jspeech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the Web Speech API. Although you can create custom grammars (which are *collections* of words), you can't define custom dictionaries or vocabularies (which are the words themselves). In your case, you'll need to define a custom vocabulary that includes individual phonemes as the words, and then limit your grammar to only choose words from your custom vocabulary. There are a few paid cloud-based services that will allow you to do this.

For example, using IBM Watson, you could [create a custom language model](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-languageCreate) and then [add words to the model](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-languageCreate#addWords) (in your case, each phoneme would be a "word"). Normally, a custom language model is blended with a general language model, but you wouldn't want that, so you would [set the customization weight](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-languageUse#weight) to 1.0 (meaning it would *only* use your custom language model).

There are other ways you could go about it too, but I doubt you'd find a purely web-based solution that doesn't involve a paid service. If you're able to move to a native platform (or create your own web-based service on the server), then you have a few more options. For example, CMUSphinx would allow you to [create a custom dictionary](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialdict/) to use with Sphinx4 on the server or PocketSphinx on mobile. Although CMUSphinx isn't the most accurate system for large-vocabulary applications, your custom vocabulary would be tiny, so CMUSphinx would perform very well.

Comment: Thanks David for the detailed answer. So as I understand, I'll have to create my own web-service (probably hosted on a cloud somewhere) and send a short recording of the spoken syllable by the web browser. Is that correct?

Comment: @Forepick If you need to be on web (not native mobile or desktop), then yes, you'll need to do the speech recognition on the server (whether it's your own or a cloud service). I would set up Sphinx4 on a server and then use WebSockets to stream the audio data to the server in real time. Then you can send the recognition response back over the same socket.